# Database design, which table has the foreign key

Tags: sql, database-design, data-modeling

I have an Table `USER` (USER_ID, PASSWORD, NAME, ...) and an Table `ACCESS_ROLES` for the Users, every user can have one `ACCESS_ROLE` (ONE-TO-ONE).

Which table has the Foreign Key?
I would put the `USER_ID` into `ACCESS_ROLES` table. Is there any best practice approach?

Comment: If it is One-To-One, then it sounds like all should go into the same table? Well, that really depends on what you need.

Comment: Sounds more like Many-to-One (as many users can have one access_role)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you will be having a one-to-one relationship, the solution suggested by Philip Kelley is better. Just add a new column in `USER` called `access_role_id` and then do the foreign key on the `USER` table like this:

```
ALTER TABLE USER ADD CONSTRAINT fk_access_roles_users
                 FOREIGN KEY (access_role_id) 
                 REFERENCES ACCESS_ROLES(access_role_id);
```

Do not add `USER_ID` into `ACCESS_ROLES` table, as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a fixed set of access roles and any number of users, where a user is assigned one and only one access role, and any number of users can be assigned a given access rule [this is how I interpret your question], then you would put a column like "AccessRoleId" in your USERS table and add a foreign key constraint into ACCESS_ROLES.

Comment: Shouldn't the foreign key constraint be into the USER table then?

Comment: As per your reply, no. If UserId is a column in Access_Roles and an FK into Users, then that means each access role is associated with one and only one user... and potentially many users will have no assigned access role.

Comment: @DanielVassallo the foreign key constraint is applied to ACCESS_ROLES table to prevent people from deleting records in access_roles if there are any user records that reference them

Answer (score 2):

- If every USER has exactly (or at most) one ACCESS_ROLE.
- One ACCESS_ROLE can have multiple USERs

Then:

- FK parent is ACCESS_ROLE and links to the PK of the ACCESS_ROLES table
- FK child is USERS and the FK column is the ACCESS_ROLE column

Note: the foreign key "parent" column(s) must have be constrainted unique. If you have multiple users per ACCESSROLE, the FK *must* be from USERS to ACCESSROLES

In SQL Server

```
ALTER TABLE USERS WITH CHECK ADD
CONSTRAINT FK_USERS_ACCESS_ROLES FOREIGN KEY (ACCESS_ROLE) REFERENCES ACCESS_ROLES (ACCESS_ROLE /*PK?*/)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a One-To-One mapping, I would put the foreign key into the table that you will be querying most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a foreign key to ACCESS_ROLES

and the following to enforce one to one mapping

```
UNIQUE (ACCESS_ROLES_ID, USER_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any best practice approach?

**Yes, there is!**

Like a `primary key`, a `foreign key` is also a type of `constraint` placed on one or more columns in a table.

The `foreign key` establishes a link between the key columns and related columns in another table. (You can also link the foreign key columns to columns within the same table.)

**The table that contains the foreign key is considered the child table, and the table that the foreign key references is the parent table.**

**Key Points**

1. The `foreign key` must reference a `primary key` or `unique constraint`, although that reference can be on the same table or on a different table.
2. A `foreign key` must also have the same number of columns as the number of columns in the referenced constraint, and the data types must match between corresponding columns.
3. Unlike `Primary key`, `Foreign key` columns can contain `NULL` values.

Comment: At least parts of this is copied verbatim from https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/questions-about-primary-and-foreign-keys-you-were-too-shy-to-ask/  - please give credit to original authors.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I understand the question or not: I think the access_table should have the Foreign Key.

Comment: If you are not sure about the question, don't waste your valuable time answering that.